# UIDocumentStateSavingError in SaveToURL

Tags: core-data, uimanageddocument

I am trying to save coredata file with some changes (locally, not through iCloud) but the "saveToURL" method completion handler is not invoked. With the debugger I saw that the file is in state UIDocumentStateSavingError.
I haven't seen any explanation in the documentation, what is this error and where is has come from. any suggestions / best practices or clues?

Thanks